# Is interference of two light waves supposed to produce another light wave?

Tags: optics, waves, visible-light, interference

This may sound like a weird question.

I was reading about interference of light. Consider this:

Suppose two light waves interfere such that their respective electric field vectors are equal and parallel but their respective magnetic field vectors are equal and anti-parallel. In such a case, the electric field doubles up and magnetic field cancels. Now I believe that interference is supposed to produce another light wave. However in my case, the light wave produced has an electric field but not a magnetic field. How is this possible?

What am I missing here?

Comment: The only way to do this is with two equal and opposite waves, and the result would be a standing wave. This isn't a propagating wave so the fact it has no magnetic field does not contradict the Maxwell equations.

Comment: @JohnRennie Can you write the same as the answer? I would accept it :).